# CSS: Image scroll on hover doesn't work on Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

so I've made a website using Elementor and I tweak some css code to set the scroll effect on hover for my images. However, today I noticed something really rare - when I visit the site using Safari, the images doesn't flow smoothly from top to the button, instead of it all you can see it's the top of the image and the very end of it. Here is the website that this issue is appearing https://ambachtcreative.be/en/website-design-agency-kempen/

I spend hours looking for some solution, but couldn't find anything that is related to my problem. The CSS code that is used is:

```
selector .elementor-image a img {
    height: 390px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top center;
    transition: object-position 3s;
}

selector .elementor-image:hover img {
    object-position: bottom center;
}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Thanks!